# matrix $T$ irreducible implies $T+I$ is primitive

Tags: linear-algebra

In the beginning of page 2 of [these notes](http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/685fa12/sternberg_perron_frobenius.pdf):

So the setup: A matrix $T$ is primitive if all entries of $T^k$ are positive for some fixed $k$.  A matrix is irreducible if each entries $(i,j)$ can be made positive in $T^k$ for some $k(ij)$($k$ depends on i,j).

I don't understand the reasoning for matrix $T$ irreducible implies matrix $I+T$ primitive. So $(I+T)^k=I+kT+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}T^2+...$ So then the $i,j$ entries of one of the term $\binom{k}{i}T^i$ will be positive, but how can you grantee it stays positive when adding to the other terms in the binary expansion?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two definitions (irreducible, primitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an important part of the definition (emphasis added):

> A ***non-negative*** matrix square T is called **primitive** if there is a $k$ such that all the entries of $T^k$ are positive. It is called **irreducible** if for any $i, j$ there is a $k = k(i, j)$ such that $\left(T^k\right)_{ij} > 0$.

Here,

> We say that a real matrix $T$ is **non-negative** [...] if all the entries
>   of $T$ are non-negative [...]

So assume $T$ irreducible, ***and implicitly that*** that all components of $T$ are non-negative. Take $k = \max_{i,j} k(i,j)$. Then each component of $(I+T)^k$ is a sum of non-negative quantities. Now by irreducibility, at least one term in the binomial expansion of this is non-vanishing. Hence $I+T$ is primitive with this choice of $k$.